# How do you connect twitter account to facebook account in your application?

Tags: facebook, twitter

Say someone signs up with facebook. Then he wants to tweet a place. Well, I need to connect his facebook account with the account he created using twitter.

Is it commonly done?

Answer (score 1):

Usually a custom application has its own database of its native user accounts and then each native user account can be associated with external services accounts.
Say, your user can associate their Facebook account and their Twitter account with their native account in your application, and then interact with those external services alike.

Comment: You can use facebook to sign up to stackoverflow.

Comment: @JimThio, that is right, one can sign up with a social network profile, but that will result with a new stackoverflow user profile creation anyway. Later the social network profile can be unlinked, but the stackoverflow profile will remain. So the actual native account is a must, while a social network profile is just an optional key and information source. You can link multiple social network profiles as sources to a single native account, but such a native account must exist as a destination anyway.